# How to rotate/change the orientation of ApplicationWindow QML?

Tags: qt, qml, orientation, applicationwindow

I would like to by default set my app at 180 degree orientation.  What is the API to rotate the screen at ApplicationWindow level? I have toolbars and statusbars in my app, so I need to rotate the ApplicationWindow itself.

Comment: You want it for mobile device?

Comment: For a linux embedded device.

Comment: Does the rotation is a feature of your application, or are you trying a hardware configuration issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `Page` component as main component in your `ApplicationWindow`

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Page{
        rotation: 180
        anchors.fill: parent

        footer: ToolBar{ ... }
    }
}
```

Result: [image: attached image]

Comment: Thanks :) In the code that I have, I replaced toolbar with statusbar and rotated that as well as the stackview I had. Works fine :)